# Line breaks in JSON string lost by Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, passenger, line-breaks

Hitting a bit of a brick wall here.  I'm trying to send a string containing line breaks (\n, turned to \u000a by JSON.stringify) as part of a JSON object over to a Rails app:

```
{"bob":{"id":46,"notes":"foo\u000abar\u000abaz"}}
```

This goes over the wire as this, with \u000a escaped as %5Cu000a:

```
http://localhost/bobs/46?draft=true&%7B%22bob%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A46%2C%22notes%22%3A%22foo%5Cu000abar%5Cu000abaz%22%7D%7D=
```

But the second the request hits Rubyland, the newlines disappear in a puff of ether, turning into spaces:

```
Processing Api::BobsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-19 11:01:43) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"draft"=>"true", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"46", "controller"=>"api/bobs", "bob"=>{"notes"=>"foo bar baz", "id"=>46}
```

And it's not just some logging artifact, but they're going into the database that way as well:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > Bob.find_by_id(46)
 => #<Bob id: 46, notes: "foo bar baz"...>
```

If I send eg. "\\n" instead of "\n", they come through fine:

```
Processing Api::BobsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-19 11:01:43) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"draft"=>"true", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"46", "controller"=>"api/bobs", "bob"=>{"notes"=>"foo\\nbar\\nbaz", "id"=>46}
```

What's going on, and why?

Update: A colleague vaguely recalls hearing that Passenger has been suspected of dropping some special chars, but he can't find a reference to back this up, and neither can I...?

Comment: Can you try escaping the newlines?

Comment: That should have been \\n, apparently you need to punch in \\\n to get it to show up right.

Comment: @Laas is right, json should go in the post body

Comment: asked May 19 '11 at 1:26, really ends today?

Comment: @iGian You can add a bounty to any question, new or old.

Comment: do you call `.stringify` before posting?

Comment: Yes, it already says so in the first line.

Answer (score 5):

This could be nothing, but aren't `PUT` methods meant to be `POST`'ed in RESTful Rails? `GET`-ing any URL should be repeatable w/o any change to the database.

If you changed your AJAX call to `post` you could also indicate proper content-type of `application/json` so Rails knows how to handle it.

Comment: Get requests don't typically get sent with a body and doing so would never be useful. POST/PUT/PATCH are better suited to sending json to a server. +1